# A generalization of Vajda's identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

I discovered the identity below which generalizes Vajda's identity concerning Fibonacci Numbers. The identity states that:
if $F_r$ is the rth Fibonacci number, then
$$F_{n+i+x-z}F_{n+j+y+z}-F_{n+x+y-k}F_{n+i+j+k}=(-1)^{n+x+y-k}F_{i+k-y-z}F_{j+k-x+z}$$

Note that Vajda's identity states that:
$$F_{n+i}F_{n+j}-F_{n}F_{n+i+j}=(-1)^{n}F_{i}F_{j}$$

> **Proof**

$$F_{n+i+x-z}F_{n+j+y+z}-F_{n+x+y-k}F_{n+i+j+k}=(-1)^{n+x+y-k}F_{i+k-y-z}F_{j+k-x+z} \tag{1}$$

We know from Binet's formula for generating nth Fibonacci number that
if
$$\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}, \varphi = \frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}$$
then

$$F_r = \frac{\phi^r - \varphi^r}{\sqrt 5}$$

where $F_r$ is the rth Fibonacci number\

From (1), let

$$\alpha = F_{n+i+x-z}F_{n+j+y+z} \tag{2}$$

$$\beta = F_{n+x+y-k}F_{n+i+j+k}\tag{3}$$

$$\gamma = (-1)^{n+x+y-k} F_{i+k-y-z}F_{j+k+z-x}\tag{4}$$

such that
$$\alpha -\beta = \gamma \tag{5}$$

We can see that to prove (1), it suffices to show that (5) is true\

Also, let
$$P_1=\frac{\phi^{2n+i+x+j+y}}{5},$$
$$P_2=\frac{\varphi^{2n+i+x+j+y}}{5},$$
$$P_3=\frac{\phi^{n+i+x-z}\varphi^{n+j+y+z}}{5},$$
$$P_4=\frac{\phi^{n+j+y+z}\varphi^{n+i+x-z}}{5},$$ $$P_5=\frac{\phi^{n+x+y-k}\varphi^{n+i+j+k}}{5},$$
$$P_6=\frac{\phi^{n+i+j+k}\varphi^{n+x+y-k}}{5}$$
$$P_7=\phi^{i+k-y-z}\varphi^{j+z+k-x},$$
$$P_8=\phi^{j+z+k-x}\varphi^{i+k-y-z},$$
$$P_9=\phi^{2k+i+j-x-y},$$
$$P_{10}=\varphi^{2k+i+j-x-y}$$
$$P_{11}= F_{i+k-y-z}F_{j+k+z-x}$$

From (2), we see that

$$\alpha = F_{n+i+x-z}F_{n+j+y+z}$$
$$\alpha = \left(\frac{\phi^{n+i+x-z}- \varphi^{n+i+x-z}}{\sqrt 5}\right)\left(\frac{\phi^{n+j+y+z}- \varphi^{n+j+y+z}}{\sqrt 5}\right)$$

$$\alpha = \frac{\phi^{2n+i+x+j+y}}{5}-\frac{\phi^{n+i+x-z}\varphi^{n+j+y+z}}{5}-\frac{\phi^{n+j+y+z}\varphi^{n+i+x-z}}{5}+\frac{\varphi^{2n+i+x+j+y}}{5}$$

$$\alpha = P_1 - P_3 - P_4 + P_2 \tag{6}$$

From (3), we see that

$$\beta = F_{n+x+y-k}F_{n+i+j+k}$$
$$\beta = \left(\frac{\phi^{n+x+y-k}- \varphi^{n+x+y-k}}{\sqrt 5}\right)\left(\frac{\phi^{n+i+j+k}- \varphi^{n+i+j+k}}{\sqrt 5}\right)$$

$$\beta =\frac{\phi^{2n+i+x+j+y}}{5} - \frac{\phi^{n+x+y-k}\varphi^{n+i+j+k}}{5}-\frac{\phi^{n+i+j+k}\varphi^{n+x+y-k}}{5}+ \frac{\varphi^{2n+i+x+j+y}}{5}$$

$$\beta = P_1 - P_5 - P_6 + P_2 \tag{7}$$

Deducting (7) from (6) gives
$$\alpha - \beta = (P_5 + P_6) -(P_3 + P_4)\tag{8}$$

From (8), let
$$V_1 = -(P_3 + P_4)$$
$$V_2 = (P_5 + P_6)$$

then

$$V_1 = -\left(\frac{\phi^{n+i+x-z}\varphi^{n+j+y+z}}{5} + \frac{\phi^{n+j+y+z}\varphi^{n+i+x-z}}{5}\right)$$
$$V_1 = -\frac{(\phi\varphi)^{n+x+y-k}}{ (\phi\varphi)^{n+x+y-k} }\left(\frac{\phi^{n+i+x-z}\varphi^{n+j+y+z}}{5} + \frac{\phi^{n+j+y+z}\varphi^{n+i+x-z}}{5}\right)$$
$$V_1 = - \frac{1}{5}((\phi\varphi)^{n+x+y-k})\left(\frac{\phi^{n+i+x-z}}{\phi^{n+x+y-k}} \frac{\varphi^{n+j+y+z}}{\varphi^{n+x+y-k}}+ \frac{\phi^{n+j+y+z}}{\phi^{n+x+y-k}} \frac{\varphi^{n+i+x-z}}{\varphi^{n+x+y-k}}\right)$$

$$V_1 =-\frac{1}{5} ((\phi\varphi)^{n+x+y-k})(\phi^{i+k-y-z}\varphi^{j+z+k-x} + \phi^{j+z+k-x}\varphi^{i+k-y-z})$$
Note that
$$\phi\varphi = -1$$
$$V_1 =-\frac{1}{5} ((-1)^{n+x+y-k})(P_7 + P_8)$$

Also,

$$V_2 = \left(\frac{\phi^{n+x+y-k}\varphi^{n+i+j+k}}{5} + \frac{\phi^{n+i+j+k}\varphi^{n+x+y-k}}{5}\right)$$
$$V_2 = \frac{ (\phi\varphi)^{n+x+y-k} }{ (\phi\varphi)^{n+x+y-k} }\left(\frac{\phi^{n+x+y-k}\varphi^{n+i+j+k}}{5} + \frac{\phi^{n+i+j+k}\varphi^{n+x+y-k}}{5}\right)$$
$$V_2 = \frac{1}{5} ((\phi\varphi)^{n+x+y-k})\left(\frac{\phi^{n+x+y-k}}{\phi^{n+x+y-k}} \frac{\varphi^{n+i+j+k}}{\varphi^{n+x+y-k}}+ \frac{\phi^{n+i+j+k}}{\phi^{n+x+y-k}} \frac{\varphi^{n+x+y-k}}{\varphi^{n+x+y-k}}\right)$$

$$V_2 = \frac{1}{5}((\phi\varphi)^{n+x+y-k})(\phi^{0} \varphi^{2k+i+j-x-y} + \phi^{2k+i+j-x-y}\varphi^{0})$$

$$V_2 = \frac{1}{5}((\phi\varphi)^{n+x+y-k})(\phi^{2k+i+j-x-y} + \varphi^{2k+i+j-x-y})$$

Note that
$$\phi\varphi = -1$$

$$V_2 = \frac{1}{5}((-1)^{n+x+y-k})(P_9 + P_{10})$$

Now, we see from (8) that

$$\alpha - \beta =(P_5 + P_6) -(P_3 + P_4)$$
$$\alpha - \beta = V_1 + V_2$$

$$\alpha - \beta = 
\frac{1}{5} ((-1)^{n+x+y-k})(P_9 -P_7 - P_8 +P_{10})\tag{9}$$

From (4), we see that

$$\gamma = (-1)^{n+x+y-k} F_{i+k-y-z}F_{j+k+z-x}$$

$$\gamma = (-1)^{n+x+y-k}(P_{11})\tag{10}$$

But

$$P_{11} = F_{i+k-y-z}F_{j+k+z-x}$$

$$P_{11} = \left(\frac{\phi^{i+k-y-z}- \varphi^{i+k-y-z}}{\sqrt 5}\right)\left(\frac{\phi^{j+k+z-x}- \varphi^{j+k+z-x}}{\sqrt 5}\right)$$

$$P_{11} = \frac{1}{5}(\phi^{i+k-y-z}- \varphi^{i+k-y-z})(\phi^{j+k+z-x}- \varphi^{j+k+z-x})$$
$$P_{11} = \frac{1}{5}(\phi^{2k+i+j-x-y} - \phi^{i+k-y-z}\varphi^{j+z+k-x} - \phi^{j+z+k-x}\varphi^{i+k-y-z} +\varphi^{2k+i+j-x-y})$$

$$P_{11} = \frac{1}{5}(P_9 - P_7 - P_8 + P_{10})\tag{11}$$

So, putting (11) in (10) gives

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{5}(-1)^{n+x+y-k}(P_9 - P_7 - P_8 + P_{10})\tag{12}$$

Since (12) equals (9) then, (5) is true which completes the proof.

> So, I want to basically ask if this kind of result is publishable.

Comment: you may want to disclose that you asked this question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4088175/87355) (with some useful feedback) and that you posted a [preprint](https://vixra.org/abs/2102.0163). You received the advice to see if _The Fibonacci Quarterly_ would be interested in your paper, did you try that? (I mention this, because there is little that this post on MO seems to add to your earlier posting on MSE.)

Comment: Maybe I didn't check correctly, but doesn't this follow directly from Vajda's identity, replacing $n$ with $n + x + y - k$, $i$ with $i + k - y - z$, and $j$ with $j + k - x - z$?

Comment: Yes, I asked this question on MSE weeks ago but I was told I will have to provide a proof of the identity which i did today but I got a downvote for providing a proof. Perhaps, the question does not suit the site which made me come here. I have posted the proof here to get people to see (1) if there is an error (2) if the proof is correct, is it rigorous enough for publication?

Comment: @Random if we set $k=x=y=z=0$, we arrive at Vajda's identity.

Comment: @Shuaib Lateef Random is correct. This directly follows from Vajda's identity. All the new variables you have defined are excessive and you never use them.

Comment: I have realized what you are pointing at. I should have used another variable, say $r$, instead of $n$ so that there won't be any confusion with the substitution.

Comment: @user127776 I don't understand what u mean by excessive. How have I not used the variables?

Answer (score 4):

Slight correction to Random's substitutions (community wiki since it's not my contribution):

define:
$${n_0}=n+x+y-k,\;\;{i_0}=i+k-y-z,\;\;{j_0}=j+k-x+z$$
substitute in Vajda's identity
$$F_{n_0+i_0}F_{n_0+j_0}-F_{n_0}F_{n_0+i_0+j_0}=(-1)^{n_0}F_{i_0}F_{j_0}$$
and you obtain the first equation in the OP,
$$F_{n+i+x-z}F_{n+j+y+z}-F_{n+x+y-k}F_{n+i+j+k}=(-1)^{n+x+y-k}F_{i+k-y-z}F_{j+k-x+z}.$$
So there is no generalization involved.

Comment: Does "there is no generalization involved" mean it is nothing new or it is a separate identity from Vajda's?

Comment: it means there is nothing new: the two identities are completely equivalent, you have just relabeled the indices.

Comment: Ok. Thanks very much for the feedback.